# Is there anything a WPF Trigger can do that a DataTrigger cannot?

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatrigger

I read on many places that a `DataTrigger` is not limited to dependency properties only (like a `Trigger`), but it can also respond to any .NET property.

So is the `DataTrigger` a superset of the `Trigger` in its capability?

Why does a `Trigger` exist when we have the `DataTrigger`?

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of triggers in `WPF`.

- Property Triggers (Simply Trigger)
- Data Triggers
- Event Triggers

`Trigger` in `WPF` are actually property triggers. So, they only work with `Dependency property`. They are mainly for depedency property values to performs actions conditionally. (*When Dependency Property meets a specified condition*)

Whereas `DataTriggers` are more powerful. They can bind to normal .net property to monitor for changes or any dependency property or another control or `StaticResources` and so on. They perform action through `bindings`. *(When bound data meets a specified condition)*

So, you could say that `Triggers` exists to provide a more **specific** action to `Dependency Properties`, instead of using more **generic** *Data Triggers* which is for any .net *data* ( of course mainly through change notification)

So, to answer your question, AFAIK, *No, there is nothing that property trigger can do that `data-trigger` cannot.*

Comment: A general rule of thumb would be that if you need to base your trigger off a property from **a different** element or from the **ViewModel**, then use a `DataTrigger`. Otherwise, you can get away with just using a `Trigger`.